# Querying composite table in Hibernate

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

I am working on a Spring-MVC application where I have a many-to-many relationship in which I have to query in 2 tables to get the values I require. I will explain in more detail.

- I have 2 tables GroupAccount, GroupMembers with many-to-many
  relationship. Now there is a junction table called membertable where
  id from GroupMembers and GroupAccount is stored.

This is what I am looking for :

- I pass a groupAccounId and username as parameters. Now, in the
  GroupMembers table, there is a username stored. In groupAccount,
  there is groupAccountId is stored.
- Now in the memberjunction, I have composite key
  memberid,GroupAccountId, I would like the member id for the username
  which has a matching groupAccountId I submit.

Below is the SQL code and Spring-mvc code to understand more better.

```
CREATE TABLE public.groupaccount (
                groupid NUMERIC NOT NULL,
                groupname VARCHAR,

                groupaccountstatus BOOLEAN DEFAULT false NOT NULL,
                adminusername VARCHAR,
                CONSTRAINT groupid PRIMARY KEY (groupid)
);

CREATE TABLE public.groupmembers (
                memberid INTEGER NOT NULL,
                musername VARCHAR
                CONSTRAINT memberid PRIMARY KEY (memberid)
);
CREATE TABLE public.memberjunction (
                memberid INTEGER NOT NULL,
                groupid NUMERIC NOT NULL,
                CONSTRAINT membergroupid PRIMARY KEY (memberid, groupid)
);
```

GroupMembersDAOImpl :#

```
 @Override
    public List<Integer> returnMemberIdWithMatchingUsername(String memberUsername) {
        session = this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        org.hibernate.Query query = session.createQuery("From GroupMembers as " +
                "n where n.memberUsername=:memberUsername");
        query.setParameter("memberUsername",memberUsername);
        List<GroupMembers> memberList = query.list();
        List<Integer> memberIdList = new ArrayList<>();
        for(GroupMembers members :memberList){
                memberIdList.add(members.getMemberid());
        }
        return memberIdList;
    }
```

GroupAccount model :

```
@Entity
@Table(name="groupaccount")
public class GroupAccount {

@Id
    @Column(name="groupid")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE,generator = "groupaccount_seq_gen")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "groupaccount_seq_gen",sequenceName = "groupaccount_seq")
    private Long groupId;

 @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(name = "memberjunction", joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "groupid")},
                inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "memberid")})
    private Set<GroupMembers> groupMembersSet = new HashSet<>();

    public void setGroupMembersSet(Set<GroupMembers> groupMembersSet){
        this.groupMembersSet = groupMembersSet;
    }
}
```

GroupMembers model class :

```
@Entity
@Table(name="groupmembers")
public class GroupMembers {
 @Id
    @Column(name="memberid")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE,generator = "groupmembers_seq_gen")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "groupmembers_seq_gen",sequenceName = "groupmembers_seq")
    private int memberid;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "groupMembersSet")
    private Set<GroupAccount> groupAccounts = new HashSet<>();

    public void setGroupAccounts(Set<GroupAccount> groupAccounts){
        this.groupAccounts = groupAccounts;
    }

    public Set<GroupAccount> getGroupAccounts(){
        return this.groupAccounts;
    }
}
```

Query I am using :

```
 @Override
    public int getMemberIdForCanvas(String memberUsername, Long groupId) {
        session = this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        org.hibernate.Query query = session.createQuery("select distinct m.memberId from GroupMembers m\n" +
                "join m.groupAccounts a\n" +
                "where a.memberUsername = :userName and m.groupId=:groupId");

        query.setParameter(memberUsername,"memberUsername");
        query.setParameter(String.valueOf(groupId),"groupId");
        int memberid = (Integer)query.uniqueResult();
        return memberid;
    }
```

Any help would be nice. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Here's [the documentation for joins and HQL](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/manual/en-US/html/ch16.html#queryhql-joins). Please read it.

The query is as simple as

```
select distinct m.memberId from GroupMembers m
join m.groupAccounts a
where a.memberUsername = :userName
```

Please also fix your naming. A `GroupMembers` instance is a *single* group member. So the class should be named `GroupMember`, without `s`. Repeating the name of the class in the fields of this class is also redundant: `member.getId()` is more readable and less verbose than `member.getMemberId()`. Same for the other fields.

Comment: Thank you for your query... I don't see where I am passing the groupAccountId in your query?? I will make the other changes you suggested.

Comment: I am updating my post to add my query.. Can you please check?

Comment: I have probably misunderstood what your query should do. I just tried simplifying the code you posted, which doesn't care about any groupAccountId. Could you post the relevant entities with the relevant members in the question?

Comment: The query doesn't use the right field name (memberid vs. memberId), and you haven't posted all the relevant code, so it's hard to say? Why don't you test it?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I have posted the query, I hope you checked it. So the query you gave me is joining with groupAccounts directly. I would like to only search for those groupAccount in memberJunction for which I am passing the id. I hope I make clear.. GroupAccount has groupId and members has memberUsername and memberId, and in memberJunction, there is a memberId matching the groupAccountId and memberId. I want to retrieve that memberId. Can you please check the method I  just posted. Its a bit urgent. Thanks.